# The difference between the gerund and the participls

Tags: phrases, verbs, nouns, gerunds

"They prefer buying organic food " in this phrase " buying " us a verb or a noun ...?

Comment: @Chappo A gerund is only ever a verb. A gerund clause is an NP, though, and thus can be a subject or an object. But it’s still only a verb, accepting adverbs and objects and rejecting adjectives and noun inflections. "Easily buying food" is different from "the easy buying of food": only the former has a gerund *buying* and thus a verb; the latter has a noun *buying* that is not a gerund and thus not a verb.

Comment: @tchrist while I hedged slightly by saying "*like* a noun", your full answer has thoroughly informed me - I've added this to my favourites for future reference :-)

Comment: @tchrist I hope the world still stands upright. A gerund **is** a noun form, with no riders. "A gerund is only ever a verb" turns everything on its head.

Comment: It's a **verb**. The traditional definition of a gerund is a word derived from a verb base which functions as or like or a noun. But that is non-committal as to whether the word is actually a verb or a noun. In your example, traditional grammar calls "buying" a gerund because functionally it is similar to the noun “food” in “environmentally-friendly food” – the similarity between the verb-form “buying” and the noun “food” being that they both head expressions with the same function, i.e. complement of “prefer”.

Answer (score 1):

Nouns can­not have di­rect ob­jects; on­ly verbs can.

*Buy­ing* is a non-fi­nite tran­si­tive verb whose di­rect ob­ject is the noun
phrase (NP), *or­gan­ic food*, which it­self com­pris­es an at­trib­u­tive
ad­jec­tive fol­lowed by its  noun.

The sub­ject of your sen­tence is third-per­son per­son­al pro­noun *They*, and
the fi­nite verb cor­re­spond­ing to that sub­ject in num­ber is *pre­fer*. The
ob­ject of the verb *pre­fer* is the en­tire non-fi­nite verb phrase *buy­ing
or­gan­ic food*.

Be­cause the syn­tac­tic roles of a sen­tence’s sub­ject and ob­ject(s) must be
them­selves noun phras­es, that means that the sub­ject and ob­ject are both
NPs — **even though nei­ther is a noun**!  A pro­noun is one type of NP, and
an *‑ing* gerund–par­tici­ple verb clause is an­oth­er type of NP. They still
aren’t nouns, of course.

Another kind of NP is the in­fini­tive clause, an­oth­er type of non-fi­nite
verb clause that can take an ob­ject. So these two are equiv­a­lent:

1. They pre­fer buy­ing or­gan­ic food.
2. They pre­fer to buy or­gan­ic food.

In both those sen­tences, the on­ly noun is *food*. Other NPs there of course
are, but on­ly that one noun alone.

To un­der­stand how English works, or in­deed any hu­man lan­guage, you need to
go be­yond triv­ial parts of speech that ap­ply to sin­gle words on­ly, nev­er to
mul­ti­word phras­es. You need to look at the gram­mat­i­cal roles that the
var­i­ous syn­tac­tic con­stituents are play­ing, and for that you need a more
mod­ern mod­el of lan­guage than the ba­by steps that Δι­ον­ύσ­ιος ὁ Θρᾷξ
(Di­ony­si­us Thrax) gave us with his eight icon­ic parts of speech lo these
twen­ty-one hun­dred years ago.

Comment: I don't know if this scholarly exposition would benefit an essentially ELL question in any way. MISS?