# What part of speech comes after "be better off"?

Tags: parts-of-speech

For example, in a sentence:

> If you've got bags, you're better off taking a taxi.

What part of speech is the "taking a taxi" part? Is it a gerund or a participle?

I know the difference between these parts of speech (or at least, I hope so =)). I'm asking this because the phrase "be better off" is totally senseless to me, and currently I'm just taking  for granted the scheme of mixing "be better off + ~something~?".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The difference between the gerund and the participls](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/186685/the-difference-between-the-gerund-and-the-participls)

Comment: The phrase "taking a taxi" is a participle here. If you cannot replace it with a noun, then it isn't a gerund.

Comment: "Taking a taxi" is a clause. Incidentally, gerund and participle are not parts of speech, but simply different kinds of non-finite verb. Trad grammar analyses "taking" as a present participle, but modern grammar calls it simply a gerund-participle.

Comment: Semantically, the idiom "better off" means "in a better position". You could have found that out by looking in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Ever wonder if you'd be better off dead?

We can hope not.   It isn't a pleasant idea.   It is, however, a common enough cliche and a useful example.  Here, the thing that follows "better off" is the common adjective "dead".

> You're better off dead. 
> You're better off taking a taxi.

The first example here gives us reason to speculate about a dead person.   The second, a person taking a taxi.   Both of these structures, the common adjective "dead" and the participial phrase "taking a taxi", serve an attributive function.   They are acting as modifiers, not as nominative references.

When an *-ing* form does the same job that is typical of a common adjective, the traditional label for that form is *present participle*.

Answer (score 0):

- [to be] better off or worse off

**is an idiomatic expression or idiom.**

**Idioms often function in peculiar ways that have their own logic.** Native speakers know how to use them instinctively (they are learned by being heard when used by other native speakers as one grows up, etc.)

**Better off** (or worse off) can be followed by clauses introduced by *now that*, *after x*, or **if x** or a **gerund or gerund phrase** or **prepositional phrases** or **just an adjective.**

Let's take a look at these examples from the Collins Dictionary:

[better off in CD](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/better-off)

> be better off

1. to have more money than you had in the past or more money than most other people:

- Obviously we're better off **now that** we're both working.
- When his parents died, he found himself $100,000 better off (= he had $100,000 more than before). [adjective]

2. to be in a better situation, **if or after something happens**:

- He'd be better off working for a bigger company.

2. implies if = He'd be better off if he were working for a bigger company.

That said, we can turn the sentence another way.

- **Working for a bigger company**, he is now better off.
- **Working for a bigger company** is a good thing.

working for a bigger company = a gerund phrase.

But even: "He is better off working" or He is worse off not working", are gerunds.
WHEREAS:
"He's better off at home". is a prepositional phrase.
"She's better off rich". is an adjective.

[I think I covered most of these idioms' peculiarities alluded to above. The point for a learner is to internalize examples so as to be able to refer to them in the future. ]

Non-gerund nouns cannot come after "to be better" or "to be worse off":
For example, "You'd be better off a bird" is not grammatical and would be said: You'd be better off **as a bird**.  I suspect that this is because better off follows the comparative rule for better: "You'd be better as a bird".

[idioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom)